# Angularjs orderBy child property

Tags: angularjs

Hi I need to order an angular list based on a child property.

I have this model:

```
  $scope.data = [{name:"John",type:{talent:"genius",val:99}},
                 {name:"Paul",type:{talent:"genius",val:89}},
                 {name:"Ringo",type:{talent:"lucky",val:29}}];
```

I need to display a list of name of only talented people. So I was trying something like this:

```
item in data|orderBy:{type.val}
```

http://jsbin.com/ObIqUyix/4/edit

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
item in data|orderBy:'type.val'
```